# Fluent NHibernate - Castle Dynamic Proxy - trust issue on localhost

Tags: iis-7, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

A while back I had a problem running an app using NHibernate on the production box. The answer (thanks to stackoverflow - questions/1469408/) was to change to full trust. 
This worked great - however now I am trying to run the same application on IIS7.5 on localhost and am having the same problem. The .Net trust level is set to "full internal" so there shouldn't be a problem. Has anyone else ran into this problem? And if so, what was your resolution.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the application pool to LocalSystem fixed it.
http://blog.igorware.com/2009/10/login-failed-for-user-iis.html

Comment: Please tell me you aren't doing this on an internet facing production server? That blog article is bad bad bad advice.